# Flutter: Inline multiple widget

Tags: flutter

I am trying to show inline widgets like Circle Avatar, Text widget with some texts and icons.
Below is the code I have written but when i run output is not inline.

I am expecting like this

```
Photo ---> Text ----> Text with Icon
      ---> More Text ---> Text
```

Currently, i am getting like this.

```
Photo
Text
Text with Icon
More Text
Text
```

Here is the code.

If showdata is true then it will show another set of widget and if its false then differnt set.

```
Widget buildList1(BuildContext context, int index) {
      return  InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          String tag = lists[index].tag ;
          print(tag);
         // navigateToFollowing(following, id, index);
        },
      child: (showdata) ?
      Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      width: double.infinity,
      height: (showdata) ? 70 : 180,
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 30),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 40),
      child: 
       Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children:     <Widget>[

               
                
                 Text(
                        "Trending Posts ",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: primary, fontSize: 12, letterSpacing: .3)),

                Text(
              '#' + lists[index].tag, 
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: primary,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 18),
                ),
                Text(
                        lists[index].count + ", Posts ",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: primary, fontSize: 13, letterSpacing: .3)),
              
               ] 
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      )
               : 
              child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: (showdata) ? 70 : 180,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 30),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 40),
               child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
          
                    Expanded(
                      child: Column(
                        
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: 
                        <Widget>[ 

                          //Posts
                                
                            Container(
                              width: 70,
                              height: 70,
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top:5, right: 5, bottom: 5),
                              child: CircleAvatar(
                                        radius: 50,
                                        backgroundColor: Color(0xff476cfb),
                                        child: ClipOval(
                                          child: Image.network(
                                            searchlists[index].profilePhoto, 
                                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                            ),
                                        ),
                              ),
                        
                            ),
                          Expanded(
                            child:
                            Column(
                              
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                              searchlists[index].name, 
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: primary,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 18),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 6,
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Icon(
                                      Icons.location_on,
                                      color: secondary,
                                      size: 20,
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 5,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      "Last Seen on -" + searchlists[index].lastLogin,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: primary, fontSize: 13, letterSpacing: .3)),
                                  ],
                                ), 
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 6,
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Icon(
                                      Icons.timer,
                                      color: secondary,
                                      size: 20,
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 5,
                                    ),
                                    
                                    Text(
                                    searchlists[index].registrationDate ,
                                    
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: primary, fontSize: 13, letterSpacing: .3)),
                                  ],
                                ), 
                      
                          ],
                    
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
               ),
            ),
        ],
          
      ),
        ), 
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap in Row() widget

```
 Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        CircleAvatar(),
        Text()
        ....
      ],
    )
```

Comment: Let me try your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to get the layout of

```
Photo ---> Text ----> Text with Icon
      ---> More Text ---> Text
```

would be to wrap the widgets in multiple `Row`'s

```
 Column(
   children: <Widget>[
      Row(
         children: <Widget>[
           Photo(), Text(), Text(), Icon(),
         ],
      ),
      Row(
         children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(), Text(), Text(),
          ],
       )
    ],
  ),
```

The `Expanded` will push your text to the far side of the screen.

`Flex` is another option you can use to be able to customize your layout a bit more. There is quite a few options available to you so i am no doubt missing some here

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will give it a try.

Comment: I think this approach is too restrictive when you are working with variable text. I would suggest looking into the [Wrap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html) widget.

Comment: Considering all elements in the initial question were given a hard set height and width the contents of said elements should be handled inside them. Also a wrap would not give you the desired layout if you overflowed it, it would instead wrap onto the next line and fill space. 
There is definitely better ways to make more dynamic layouts to achieve the original questions goal. However, this is very static components and a 2 year old answer

Answer (score 0):

```
Text.rich(
                                    TextSpan(
                                      text:
                                          'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                      ),
                                      children: <InlineSpan>[
                                        WidgetSpan(
                                            alignment:
                                                PlaceholderAlignment.baseline,
                                            baseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
                                            child: ConstrainedBox(
                                              constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                                                maxWidth: 200,
                                              ),
                                              child: Padding(
                                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                  left: 8.0,
                                                ),
                                                child: Text(
                                                  '#Friends #atWork',
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors.black,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            )),
                                        const TextSpan(
                                          text: '.',
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
```